# how to limit the scope of akka http rejections to their own routes

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

here is my route structure

```
classA {

implicit def classARejectionHandler =
    RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
      .handle {
        case MissingCookieRejection(cookieName) =>
          complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = "No cookies, no service!!!"))
      }
      .handle {
        case AuthorizationFailedRejection =>
          complete((Forbidden, "You're out of your depth!"))
      }
      .handle {
        case ValidationRejection(msg, _) =>
          complete((InternalServerError, "That wasn't valid! " + msg))
      }
      .handleAll[MethodRejection] { methodRejections =>
        val names = methodRejections.map(_.supported.name)
        complete((MethodNotAllowed, s"Can't do that! Supported: ${names mkString " or "}!"))
      }
      .handleNotFound { complete((NotFound, "Not here!")) }
      .result()

val route:Route = handleRejections(classARejectionHandler) {
concat(
        path("event-by-id") {
          get {
      }
} ,
  path("create-event") {
          post {
      }
}
}

classB {

implicit def classBRejectionHandler =
    RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
      .handle {
        case MissingCookieRejection(cookieName) =>
          complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = "No cookies, no service!!!"))
      }
      .handle {
        case AuthorizationFailedRejection =>
          complete((Forbidden, "You're out of your depth!"))
      }
      .handle {
        case ValidationRejection(msg, _) =>
          complete((InternalServerError, "That wasn't valid! " + msg))
      }
      .handleAll[MethodRejection] { methodRejections =>
        val names = methodRejections.map(_.supported.name)
        complete((MethodNotAllowed, s"Can't do that! Supported: ${names mkString " or "}!"))
      }
      .handleNotFound { complete((NotFound, "Not here!")) }
      .result()

val route:Route = handleRejections(classBRejectionHandler) {
      path("fileUploads") {
        post {
    }
}
}
}

class Demo extends App {

def main {
val a =new classA
val b = new ClassB

val routes = a~b
      val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(MainRouter.routes, hostName, port)

}


}
```

now the problem is when i hit the route `localhost:8080/fileuploads` with method `POST` with its params the route works when

- i remove the rejections from `classA`
- it works when i remove the rejection both from `classA` and `classB`

route does not work when

- the rejection code is present in both `classA` and `classB` classes
- only in `classA`

by does not work i means i get the response

```
Not here!
```

which is `classA`'s `handleNotFound` rejection handler is rejecting the route of `classsB` because i am hitting the route of `classB` According to my understanding there is some problem in chaining the routes but i need to put different routes in different classes this is my requirement 
how can i stop getting rejection of a desired route from other chained routes rejection handlers?